# Sum of zeros of $P(x)$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots

I asked this question here before too, but vaguely, hopefully, this time will be a better attempt:

> There are nonzero integers $a$, $b$, $r$, and $s$ such that the complex number $r+si$ is a zero of the polynomial $P(x) = x^3 - ax^2 + bx - 65$. For each possible combination of $a$ and $b$, let $p_{a,b}$ be the sum of the zeroes of $P(x)$. Find the sum of the $p_{a,b}$'s for all possible combinations of $a$ and $b$.

Let the integer zero be $k$

I got that:

$a=2r+k$

$b=2rk+r^2+s^2$

$65=n(r^2+s^2)$

Then I got:

Cases, not in order: $r^2 + s^2 = 13, r^2 + s^2 = 1, r^2 + s^2 = 5, r^2 + s^2 = 65$

For case 1: $r = \{2, -2, 1, -1 \}$

$\sum a = 2(\sum r) + k \implies a = 13$

Then for case 2: $r^2 + s^2 = 13$, it is that,

$\sum a = 2(\sum r) + k \implies a = 5$

Case 3:

$\sum a = 2(\sum r) + k \implies a = 65$

Case 4:

$\sum a = 2(\sum r) + k \implies a = 1$

$$\sum a = 1 + 65 + 5 + 13 = 84$$

The answer is $(80)$, but I got $84$?

Comment: [Statement of the problem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4910) (#10) and [related discussion](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h525072p2969823) on *Art of Problem Solving*. Since you wrote the same question there, it's nice to tell :)

Comment: Your work is extremely hard to understand. You should put more steps to explain your logic because you make many jumps that make it hard, at least for me, to understand what you're doing.